# ODAC 64bit + Visual Studio 2010 + ODAC 32bit(In VM)

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, odp.net

Okay, so I have written a program in my virtual machine using C# and an Oracle DB. Everything works fine in there. Now I want to use the same program to connecto to the same DB but from another computer, lets say, my host system. 
I have installed VS2010 64Bit and ODAC 64bit too, I can see the Oracle Command, Oracle Connection in the Toolbox, but when I try to add an Oracle Connection item i get an error: `The provider is not compatible with Oracle Client version`.
This happens even when I try to start a new project.

1. How can I check my Ora Client version?
2. What files to I exactly need
   to install to get ODP to work on 64bits.
3. Is there any other way I should do it?

The files I downloaded are in [this link](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html&ei=pM59Upu1AsPUkQeBzYDgAg&usg=AFQjCNGHr5Rv0IrMLu-B43W06wp-AMLvkg&sig2=vPWYXuoGyKK7dOBuo_rkEg&bvm=bv.56146854,d.eW0)

Comment: Install Oracle client in that machine and give a try.

Comment: I have Oracle Client in both Host and Client machines.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is something to do with the `bit version (32/64 bit)` issue, There is a mismatch in the processor architecture of the components/dlls.

1. Check the bit version of the oracle data access dll you have added as project referene
2. Check the bit version of the oracle client installed in the machine.
3. Check the GAC(Global Assembly Cache) in and remove if there is any Oracle data access dlls.(your application might be loading wrong dll from GAC)

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

1. Uninstall VS2010 64 bit.
2. (Maybe apply CCleaner to clean registries)
3. Install VS2010 32 bit.
4. Install ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit

And that made my project work. Thank you for your time!